# How to use pointers and pointer aritmetic

Tags: c++, pointers

: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
: error C2227: left of '->name' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

how do i fix this so this error doesn't happen

```
for(int index = 0; index < (numStudents); index++)
{
    if (student(index + 1)->score >= 90 )
        student(index + 1)->grade = 'A';
    else if (student(index + 1)->score >= 80 )
        student(index + 1)->grade = 'B';
    else if (student(index + 1)->score >= 70 )
        student(index + 1)->grade = 'C';
    else if (student(index + 1)->score >= 60 )
        student(index + 1)->grade = 'D';
    else 
        student(index + 1)->grade = 'F';
}
```

heres the structure:

```
struct StudentType
{
    string name;
    int score;
    char grade;
};
```

and here is the pointer :
StudentType* student;

Comment: What does `student()` return?

Comment: You posted the wrong part of code, there is no use of the name member here.

Comment: well this is a void function but StudentType* student and student type is    
     struct StudentType
        {
         string name;
         int score;
         char grade;
        };

Comment: I can't see any pointers in this code except whatever student() returns. I also don't see any reference to 'name' either. student isn't an array by any chance is it?

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you need to do

```
student[index + 1]
```

instead of

```
student(index + 1)
```

You should really specify what is `student` so people can answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment answers it appears student is a pointer. In that case `student(index + 1)` is not valid syntax. I think you mean `student[index + 1]`.

Further critique - 1 based arrays in C are bad form. Consider starting at 0 like everyone else in C

Answer (score 1):

Is students a method/function or an array?  Perhaps this is what you mean:

```
for (int index = 0; index < numStudents; index++) {
   // ensure that we don't go past the end of the student array
   if (index + 1 == numStudents) break;

   if (student[index + 1]->score >= 90) student[index + 1]->grade = 'A';
   else if (student[index + 1]->score >= 80) student[index + 1]->grade = 'B';
   else if (student[index + 1]->score >= 70) student[index + 1]->grade = 'C';
   else if (student[index + 1]->score >= 60) student[index + 1]->grade = 'D';
   else student[index + 1]->grade = 'F';
}
```

Though I don't understand why you are avoiding the first student (students[0]). You know arrays are zero-based, right? You could achieve the same effect without all of the 'index + 1' if you initialize the index variable to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: but it need to be in pointer arithmetic am i doing it completely wrong because i didn't even realize that it skipped 0

Comment: So you mean that you must use:
<pre>
if ((student + index)->score >= 90) (student + index)->grade = 'A';
</pre>
I find that harder to read, but I guess if you *must* use pointer arithmetic there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what it's trying to tell you is that the `student` function doesn't take just one argument. Since it couldn't actually call the function the second part of the error then tells you it can't be used to the left of `->`

It's hard to say without more detail (specifically, what is `student`), but assuming `student` is a vector or array most likely you meant to say `student[index + 1]` instead of using the parentheses.